# declare multiple arraylists

Tags: java

is it possible to declare 2 array lists in the same line?
e.g:

```
List<String> mm= new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> kk= new ArrayList<String>();
```

Is it then possible to do something like:

```
List<String> mm,kk= new ArrayList<String>();
```

Obviously, I get a compile error when I do the above, and was wondering how could one declare 2 lists in the same line.

Comment: Your example compiles fine, but it only initializes `kk`.

Comment: If I were a tester or a developer looking at your code for where kk was defined, I would find your first example cleaner and easier to follow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want that, you should do:

```
List<String> list_1 = new ArrayList<String>(), list_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: James, please don't forget to click the green tick mark next to the answer :).

Comment: @JamesW: That's bad coding style, I wouldn't use this.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: yes, you can [declare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_%28computer_programming%29) 2 variables in the same expression. `List<String> mm,kk;` is declaring two lists.

Note that the operation `kk = new ArrayList<String>();` is **not a declaration**, it is an [assigment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_programming%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare them in the same line, but you cannot initialize them.
So

```
List<String> mm,kk;
```

is possible but then you still have to initialize them

```
mm = new ArrayList<String>();
kk = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

What @fge wrote is the correct way. However make sure you don't initialize them in a single line like:

```
mm = kk = new ArrayList<String>();
```

as this would lead to both the lists pointing to the same arraylist object and would mess up both the lists.

This single line initialization can be done for primitive data types but not for reference data types.